# Foreign key name is not showing in ForeignKeyFailedException in MySQL version 8.0.28

Tags: mysql, exception, foreign-keys

My code is throwing a foreign key exception.
MySQL 8.0.12 is showing the complete exception message (with foreign key name) but  when I upgrade to MySQL to 8.0.28 it is not showing the complete exception message.

Exception in MySQL 8.0.12:

> `` Exceptions.ForeignKeyFailedException: Upsert failed as some referenced entity doesnt exist. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`SchemaName`.`table name`, CONSTRAINT `foreign key name` FOREIGN KEY (`column`) REFERENCES `table name` (`column`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) ``

Exception in MySQL 8.0.28:

> `Exceptions.ForeignKeyFailedException: Upsert failed as some referenced entity doesnt exist. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

How can I show the complete exception message in MySQL 8.0.28 or higher?

Comment: That's not an error message I would expect from mysql mysql , you have also tagged c# and vb.net so where is the error being seen?..You could also test this procedure in mysql alone to rule in/out mysql incompleteness. publishing table definitions and alter statements as text would help